# How long until jxbrowser ships the latest version of Chromium (version 64)?

Tags: ecmascript-6, jxbrowser

The most recent version of JxBrowser (6.18) is currently shipping Chromium 60 which is 4 major versions behind the most recent version of Chromium. How long until a new version will be released? In Chromium 61 ES6 imports is enabled and that changes a lot in rendering pages without the need for pre-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser team is currently working on this, but the update to the Chromium version 64 will not be released before February.